# Windows Server 2008 R2 Video Card Requirements?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm considering installing Windows Server 2008 R2 at home on an old(ish) PC and relegating the machine to the basement.  One thing I'm wondering though:

Once I've installed Windows on the machine and set everything up, does the machine still need a video card installed, or can I pull it and just remote to the machine as and when I need to access it?  It seems a bit pointless needing a video card in there eating power if it's not going to be connected to a monitor.

James

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ever access the console (eg. solving a networking problem that prevents remote access) then you'll need a video card.

Unless you install extra components Windows Server will just run as SVGA (albeit allowing 1600x1200 and up resolution) not making use of any acceleration or other power hungry functions of the graphics card. If not using the console it should also go into power saving mode. Therefore the power drain will be much lower than the graphics card's maximum rating.